# Generate 2 random numbers

Tags: matlab, random, distribution, uniform-distribution

How to generate two random numbers **α, β ~ U[-1,+1]** if **β ≥ α**?

My first intention was to just generate two vectors and only take the ones which satisfy **β ≥ α** and discard the rest.

However, I think that might change the distribution.

Comment: Perhaps this question is better suited to [math.se] or [stats.se].

Comment: You can generate A ~ U(-1,+1) and B ~ U(-1,+1) but the ones you keep from B will actually be (B | B >= A) which is not ~ U(-1, + 1).  There's nothing wrong with this if that's what you want.  Are you wanting the conditional distribution?  Or just how to generate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of simple options, but some will skew the distribution a bit.

The simplest is to generate a pair of numbers and swap them to meet your condition, if necessary. This should yield a uniform distribution.

Another option is to generate α ~ [-1, +1] first, then generate β ~ U[α, +1]. Alternatively, you could generate β ~ [-1, +1] first and then α ~ [-1, β]. This option would skew since the second number is not generated uniformly.

Perhaps a better approach would be to create a 1:1 mapping of the vector (α, β) to a number line. Then generate a single number, and convert it into the 2D vector. This has the potential of providing a uniform distribution of the vector if the mapping is chosen appropriately.

Comment: I am under the impression that your 2nd solution, though computationally superior, would yield the same result as the OP's idea. +1 for the 1st suggestion which is beautiful in its simplicity :)

Comment: @Dev-iL. I think you're right. The distribution of the first solution will be much less skewed. I've added another possibility.

Comment: I saw the other solution, and I like it as well :) BTW, are you sure you wanted to revert my edit to the question?

Comment: It was an accidental reversion since I'm on mobile and everything is slow. That being said, I don't think adding a bunch of generic tags is a good idea in this case.

Comment: Method 1 yields a uniform distribution within the 2D triangular domain. Method 2 yields a uniform marginal distribution for alpha.  Challenge: make it so both marginal distributions are uniform! :)

Comment: @Cris. Or alternatively prove that it's impossible. Although I think my last suggestion of using a different mapping might be a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Mad Physicist's answer is fairly broad already, though the second solution stated produces results that are not actually random, as taking **α ~ U[-1, +1]** first would skew to the right and **β ~ U[-1, +1]** would skew to the left.

For the problem, the most straightforward solution would be to generate **α** and **β**, and then swap them if **β < α**. The results would be uniformly distributed. In Matlab:

```
a = 2 * rand - 1;
b = 2 * rand - 1;
if b < a
    [b, a] = deal(a, b);
end
disp(a)
disp(b)
```

If you mean numbers as *integers*, then simply apply the method above for integers. In Matlab:

```
a = randi([-1, 1]);
b = randi([-1, 1]);
if b < a
    [b, a] = deal(a, b);
end
disp(a)
disp(b)
```